# Python3 - Get Request with Secret

Tags: python-3.x, request

I am trying to send a get request to [Airtable to get metadata](https://airtable.com/api/meta) but I keep getting errors.

I have tried the below.

```
base_schema_url = 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/meta/bases/BaseId(replaced this)/tables'
secret_meta_token = '123'

#attempt 1
r = requests.get(base_schema_url, headers={'Authorization': secret_meta_token})
print(r.text)

#attempt 2
r = requests.get(base_schema_url,
      headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(secret_meta_token)})
print(r.text)

#attempt 3
header = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': secret_meta_token}
r = requests.get(base_schema_url, headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

I have a feeling it's because I need to pass in the user API + the Meta token but I'm not too sure how to do it.

Comment: It would be better if you add error log here for better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

user_account_api = xxx
meta_api = xxx
base_id = xxx

headers = {
    "Authorization":f"Bearer {user_account_api}",
    "x-airtable-client-secret": meta_api
}
response = requests.get(f"https://api.airtable.com/v0/meta/bases/{base_id}/tables", headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The metadata API uses a separate key that you need to send a formal request to the Airtable team by registering at the link provided at the top of the page.